# Postman https request works but restTemplate doesn't

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I make a request to the **https** URL with the postman, I get 400 response and data without any certification config. While I make the same request with restTemplate I get 404 not found with the same url. postman body :

```
{
  "Request": {
    "usernamenull": "",
    "passwordnull": ""
  },
  "username": "iceicebaby",
  "password": "12345"
}
```

and Java code:

```
HttpHeaders headers= new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("Authorization","Basic ***");
        headers.add("Accept", "*/*");
        RequestBodyModel request = new RequestBodyModel();
        request.setRequest(new UserRequest("",""));
        request.setUsername(userName);
        request.setPassword(password);
        HttpEntity<RequestBodyModel> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request,headers);
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url,requestEntity,String.class);
```

any help appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I changed my code to :

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,requestEntity,String.class);
```

and I get 302 redirect error(Location: same url, server: 'ACB') while postman works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between postman and restTemplate is because of their ways to handle redirect.

### Postman

Postman automatically redirect your request. As you can see in this screenshot, I think you're postman's automatic redirect option will be turned on too.
[image]

### restTemplate

But, restTemplate doesn't automatically redirect your requests.

## Solution

### 1. Configure restTemplate to follow redirect

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()) // Enables automatic redirect handling for all HTTP methods
        .build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = 
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

### 2. manually handle redirect

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FOUND) { // 302 redirect
    String redirectUrl = responseEntity.getHeaders().getLocation().toString();
    // get the redirect Url from header
    ResponseEntity<String> redirectedResponse = restTemplate.exchange(redirectUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class);
}
```

Comment: thank you but there is no setFollowRedirects method. can you suggets any other method instead of resttemplate like rest client or any other pache client ?

Comment: You're right..! So I changed the first solution. Hope it helps you :)